# Incorrect Certificate, potential attack?

Tags: security, certificate

when accessing google i'm having some issues, logos not loading, accounts not swaping etc. I tried to access this logo:

https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/rfr/logo_gmail_lockup_default_1x_r2.png

It's google gmail logo. The certificate i'm receiving looks like this:
[Certificate received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg5Y6.png)

I know that the certificate should look like this (image from a friend):[Correct certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7GS.png)

Is this caused by a potential attacker?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post decoded certificate.  You can use [online decoder](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like there is an SSL tomcat server in the middle. Classic [Man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).